# datagrid access in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am new to `c#` and `Database` linking that's why not able to get this by searching old posts of [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

### Code like

```
private void issueDetails()
    {
        string connectionPath = @"Data Source=Data\libraryData.dat;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True";

        using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionPath))
        {
            SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            connection.Open();
            string query = "SELECT bookno as 'Book No.',studentId as 'Student ID',  title as 'Title', author as 'Author', description as 'Description', issuedDate as 'Issued Date', dueDate as 'Due Date' FROM issuedBooks";
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "issuedBooks");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["issuedBooks"];
            dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns["Student ID"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

i used like above for getting some library book details like issuedDate and dueDate, now i want highlight a particular cell that is over dueDate .

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        Color c = Color.Black;
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 6)
        {
            if (isLate(Convert.ToString(e.Value)))
            {
                c = Color.Red;
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine(count);
            }

        }
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = c;
    }

    public string toInd(string date)
    {
        DateTimeFormatInfo fmt = new CultureInfo("fr-fr").DateTimeFormat;
        string dateString;
        DateTimeOffset offsetDate, dateig;
        string ret = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        dateString = date;
        bool ws = DateTimeOffset.TryParse(dateString, fmt, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateig);
        if (ws)
        {
            offsetDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateString, fmt);
            ret = offsetDate.Date.ToShortDateString();
            return ret;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private bool isLate(string nowS)
    {

        DateTime dueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(toInd(nowS));
        DateTime now;
        string present = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        now = Convert.ToDateTime(present);
        //Console.WriteLine(toInd(nowS));
        int a = dueDate.CompareTo(now);
        if (a >= 0)
            return false;
        else return true;
    }
```

but if use `if (isLate(Convert.ToString(e.Value)))
            {
                c = Color.Red;
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine(count); 
            }` this for number of books over due, the 'count' value increases 4 time even only two books are over due in my database because this if block access 2 times while data binding and again two time when it sorts how can i get only number over due books value

Comment: Have you tried ordering the list by the student ID in the select query?

Comment: ya i tried but still same problem ...

Comment: even i removed sorting  statement the problems comes

Comment: I am speculating here, but maybe the dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true; triggers the cellformatting event. Have you tried commenting it out or placing it before the bind to your data source?

Comment: @Aaron Ray now i removed it but still same problem again

Comment: You shouldn't do any counting like that in the CellFormatting event. You have no control over how many times infrastructure may call it. Instead, find out what's overdue once you get your data, before binding it to the grid, and then in the event just check whether the row contains the overdue book and do formatting accordingly.

Comment: Also, there's no need to call `Sort` on datagridview since it's always `DataView` that gets assigned to the `DataSource`. So you could just do this instead: `dgv.DataSource = new DataView(ds.Tables["issuedBooks"], null, "Student ID", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);`

Comment: You could add the object that represents overdue books to a HashSet in your CellFormatting event handler, and then find out how many items there are by calling the HashSet's count property after the fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

```
private void UpdateDataGridViewColor()
    {
        if (calledMethod == 2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                int j = 6;
                DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
                CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;

                if (isLate(dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    dataGridView1[j, i].Style = CellStyle;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: use this code at form load and gridview sorting for proper result

Answer (score 2):

Actually dataGridView1_CellFormatting is fired on every single cell event, including if you sort, or even if you you hover the mouse over a cell.. very expensive in terms of performance.

Instead you could use the RowsAdded event on the dgv which will be fired one time only upon addition:

```
    private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isLate(dataGridView1[6, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()))
        {
            dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            count++;
        }
    }
```